# iPhone Development: SIGABRT Error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, exception, sigabrt

I am very new at developing for the iPhone. I was trying to make a basic application, but a SIGABRT Error appears. When I press a button in the simulator the game crashes and a SIGABRT Error appears. It is NSInvalidArgumentException. 
Here is some code for the button:
.h file:

```
-(IBAction)abc;


-(IBAction)abc {
    b *aaa = [[b alloc] initWithNibName:@"b" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:aaa animated:NO];
    [aaa release];
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think there is no any such a problem in this code which may lead to sigbart..

Comment: Can you post the complete exception?

Comment: The code doesn't show anything for your problem.

Comment: Run your program under the debugger in Xcode.  It will break and tell you exactly where the problem is occurring.  There's some method somewhere that you're calling with invalid arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bast way to find SIGBART in your application is by using debugging tool where you can find exact location of application getting this signal.
Your code looks fine, maybe there will be some error in your b class file

Hope it helps....

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the method you have assigned the button to call when touched doesn't exist e.g.

```
UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 25)];

[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Make sure "myMethod" exists in your implementation file (.m file) and you have a method declaration in the header file (.h file)

```
// Header file (.h)
@interface myClass
{

}

- (void) myMethod;

@end

... 

// Implementation file (.m)

...

- (void) myMethod
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have added the button in XIB then you must have forgotten to add its event using IBAction. and bind it with Touch up inside type. if Still don't work, you need to debug and check , on Button click what procedure you are doing and at which point it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

You put the real IBAction in the .m file.